# nmap bypass iptables rules | Redhat 5.6

Tags: iptables, nmap

I have legacy system on Redhat Linux 5.6, with Nmap 4.11. ( IP: 10.11.4.22 ). I want to block access from this legacy system via every port/protocols to another server( IP: 10.11.4.24 ).

I first flush the existing rules via iptables -f

Then apply following rules

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 10.11.4.24 -j DROP 
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 10.11.4.24 -j DROP
```

After that , I am unable ping, access via ssh is restricted but when trying to confirm from nmap somehow nmap can access the destination server 10.11.4.24. How nmap is accessing the destination server to give port status.

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
631/tcp  open  ipp
792/tcp  open  unknown
3000/tcp open  ppp
5000/tcp open  UPnP
5801/tcp open  vnc-http-1
5802/tcp open  vnc-http-2
5901/tcp open  vnc-1
5902/tcp open  vnc-2
6001/tcp open  X11:1
6002/tcp open  X11:2
```

Regards
Salman

Comment: did you mean to use `-s 10.11.4.22` rather?

Comment: No I want to block traffic from 10.11.4.22  to 10.11.4.24. I am making these rules in 10.11.4.22.

Comment: In that case the second line is nonsense -- it will never match since *outbound* packets will never have a source IP of `10.11.4.24`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output line wants to drop packets that come from your intended destination:

> ```
> iptables -A OUTPUT -s 10.11.4.24 -j DROP
> ```

You probably meant to drop data going to your blocked host instead:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT --dst 10.11.4.24 -j DROP
```